# How to sort Japanese string list in TListBox Control in alphabetical order?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have list of Japanese string as follows listed in TListBox control of Delphi

I want to sort it in alphabetical order. how to achieve it in Delphi. I am using Delphi 10 Berlin IDE

コントロール
文字列
デザイニング

In C# it is possible using CultureInfo but in delphi what i have to use to perform sorting ?

Comment: I fixed your tags. You aren't using Delphi 2010. Tagging questions correctly is very important. It's not obvious to me what you mean by `TList`. That class does not naturally hold strings, nor is it a control.

Comment: Does platform matter?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "alphabetical" order?  Gojūon (五十音) order?  Iroha (いろは)?  What about kanji?

Comment: ...and if you want full, proper Gojūon sorting - with kanji lines correctly sorted together with both kana types by their phonetic pronunciation in the context of the word they are in, this is something of a challenge - see : [Can sorting Japanese kanji words be done programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4895527/327083)

Comment: @J... yes platform do matter. Gojūon (五十音) order? Iroha (いろは)? which one is preferable for global software could you please suggest?

Comment: It is TListBox, sorry for typo. could you please suggest some thing CultureInfo in delphi like c#? @DavidHeffernan

Comment: FireMonkey or VCL? As for which sort order you want to use, surely that's for you to research and decide.

Comment: Since it sounds like you don't actually know or care what the sort order is, you could just try using `.Sorted := true` on the listbox.  On windows this sorts the same way windows would (using StrCmpLogical) - I don't know about other platforms.  This produces gojuon ordering for lines that start with kana entirely followed by kanji by radical stroke order, I believe.  It's not gojuon, proper.